# Height constraint, lessThanOrEqualToConstant, but tries to achieve the constant if possible

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have two views, previewSection, & settingsEditSection. I'm trying to layout these views to achieve the following:

- previewSection's top is anchored to the top of the parent view
- previewSection has a height of 400 if possible, but it will be smaller if necessary for settingsEditSection to achieve it's minimum height
- settingsEditSection's top is anchored to bottom of previewSection
- settingsEditSection's bottom is anchored to bottom of parent view
- settingsEditSection has a height of **at least** 150

My problem is, when I give previewSection a height of `lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 400` it has an actual height of 0.

Is there some way for me to say: "height of lessThanOrEqualToConstant, x, and as long as theres room, have the height of x"?

I want the height of 150 for settingsEditSection to be the first priority, and then before making it any larger, make previewSection 400 if possible, and if there's still room after that, then settingsEditSection can get larger than 150 to fill in the space.

Here's the code that I wrote, that makes the most sense to me:

```swift
let previewSection = PreviewSection()
view.addSubview(previewSection)
let settingsEditSection = SettingsEditSection()
view.addSubview(settingsEditSection)
// Preview section
previewSection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
previewSection.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
previewSection.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
previewSection.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: topMargin).isActive = true
previewSection.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 400).isActive = true
previewSection.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: settingsEditSection.topAnchor).isActive = true
// Settings & edit section
settingsEditSection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
settingsEditSection.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
settingsEditSection.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
settingsEditSection.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: upgradeButton.topAnchor).isActive = true
settingsEditSection.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 150).isActive = true
settingsEditSection.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previewSection.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Right now, previewSection has a height of 0, and then settingsEditSection's height just spans the entire parent view.

The context of this problem for me is I'm building out [this profile page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCB9k.png), and to layout the profile & buttons to look best on both an iPhone X and an iPhone 5S, this is the best way to do it.

Comment: What is the height of the container view?

Comment: @ShreeramBhat, well that's dependent on the device. But it's the full width of the device and maybe a hight ~100px smaller than the height of the device

Comment: That is fine. The main thing is Container view height it self should not depend on height of subviews, for above thing to work. You can give a try to the code I posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use constraint priority here. After

```
previewSection.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 400).isActive = true
```

You can add one more constraint that gives a default height, but at a lower priority. Like this,

```
let previewSectionHeight = previewSection.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400)
previewSectionHeight.priority = .defaultHigh
previewSectionHeight.isActive = true
```

This will make previewSection to have a height of 400 until unless settingsEditSection pushes it up to make it small. For all of this to work you also need to give a constant height to the container view of previewSection and settingsEditSection.